# How do I find all possible values of an enum in Raku?

Tags: raku

```
enum Direction <north east south west>;
for north, east, south, west -> $dir {
    say $dir;
    ...
}
```

I don't want to repeat the list of Direction values here.  How can I programmatically get this list?

I haven't found anything in the documentation.  Closest is `.enums`, but that returns a Map of (string) key to (integer) value, not enum values.

Comment: You'd be doing the Advent of code then?

Comment: @ScimonProctor: absolutely.  https://github.com/mscha/aoc/tree/master/aoc2023

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter

```raku
enum Direction <north east south west>;
Direction.pick(*).raku
```

or

```raku
enum Direction <north east south west>;
Direction::.values.raku
```

Sorted by value

```raku
enum Direction «:2north :1east :south(10) :west(9)»;
Direction.pick(*).sort.raku
```

Sorted by definition;
if you know first and last element

```raku
enum Direction «:2north :1east :10south :9west»;
(north, *.succ ... west).raku;
```

if you don't

```raku
enum Direction «:2north :1east :10south :9west»;
(Direction.pick(*).first({ $_ === .pred }), *.succ ...^ * === *).raku
```

Comment: Thanks, Wamba!  `Direction::.values` is what I needed.  Not very obvious, but still fairly elegant if you know about it.

Comment: i’ve deleted my non answer and reflect that .keys returns strings and not the desired enum items

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but one can reconstruct a symbol from its name:

```
enum Direction <north east south west>;

for Direction.enums {
    say .key, .key.WHAT, .value, .value.WHAT, ::(.key), ::(.key).WHAT;
}
```

displays:

```
east(Str)1(Int)east(Direction)
south(Str)2(Int)south(Direction)
west(Str)3(Int)west(Direction)
north(Str)0(Int)north(Direction)
```

---

The [speculation doc for Enumerations](https://github.com/Raku/old-design-docs/blob/63e44c36351887f1eb76500d7102f0db44848d27/S12-objects.pod#enumerations:%7E:text=The%20enumeration%20typename%20itself%20may%20be%20used%20as%20a%20coercion%20operator%20from%20either%20the%20key%20name%20or%20a%20value.) says:

> The enumeration typename itself may be used as a coercion operator from either the key name or a value.

But in my 2022 Rakudo it only works for values (integers in this case):

```
for Direction.enums {
    say Direction(.value), Direction(.value).WHAT;
}
```

displays:

```
east(Direction)
south(Direction)
west(Direction)
north(Direction)
```

Comment: How to find `::(…)` in the docs?

Comment: Thanks, @raiph, but `Direction::.values` was what I was looking for.

Comment: @jubilatious1 Treat docs as amazeballs? I entered `::(` into docs.raku.org's search field. I got "`::($c).m`". (Why is that in the search index?) Clicking it took me to a page titled "`::($c).m` Combined from ...". (The closest I see to `::(...)` is "Unlike `::()` symbolic references...".) Near the start is "See primary documentation in context for Direct lookup" with a link. I clicked that and arrived at the **Direct lookup** section of the **Packages** page. I scrolled upwards and bingo, that's the right section. Like I said, treat docs as a maze/balls! (In other words, please file issues.)

Comment: @mscha Yeah, a much nicer answer! .@wamba specializes in brilliant succinct answers showing all the useful solutions. I learn lots from them almost every time. 

Comment: @raiph It would help if there was a canonical name for `::()`. For example, I can find "Enumerated Character Class" in the docs, as an equivalent to the symbolic `<[]>`. How/what to call this `::()`, other than _double-colon-thingie_ ?

Comment: @jubilatious1 The doc verbiage I quoted was "Unlike `::()` symbolic references...", so presumably that? A [search of the design doc repo for "symbolic reference"](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ARaku%2Fold-design-docs+%22symbolic+reference%22&type=code) shows the design docs used that term for the same thing. User doc presumably followed suit? A [search of the user doc for "symbolic references"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocs.raku.org+symbolic%20references) scores a match in the right section of the right page. So "symbolic reference" is presumably the canonical name.